# Daemon Tools Messages

Tags: linux, daemontools

I configured a service to run through daemontools, but while stopping svscan, I am getting messages like this:

```
[root@tcp-handler ssc_ios]# /etc/init.d/svscan stop
Stopping djb services: svscan services  logging .
[root@tcp-handler ssc_ios]# Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 800, in emit
self.flush()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 762, in flush
self.stream.flush()
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Can someone tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

One of your processes is a Python program that doesn't handle stdout going away.  Normally you shouldn't be stopping svscan though.

You should instead be interacting with daemontools through `svc`.  `svc -d /service/foo` will stop the `foo` process.  `svc -d /service/foo/log` will stop its logging.  See http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/svc.html for more options.